# Extracting data from multiple tables with Scrapy using xpath

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm extracting meta data and urls from 12 tables on a web page and while I've got it working, I'm pretty new to both xpath and scrapy so is there a more concise way I could have done this?

I was initially getting loads of duplicates as I tried a variety of xpaths and realised each table row was being repeated for each table.  My solution to that was to enumerate the tables and loop through each one grabbing the rows only for that table.  Feels like there is probably a simpler way to do it but I'm not sure now.

```
import scrapy

class LinkCheckerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'foodstandardsagency'
    allowed_domains = ['ratings.food.gov.uk']
    start_urls = ['https://ratings.food.gov.uk/open-data/en-gb/']

    def parse(self, response):

        print(response.url)
        tables = response.xpath('//*[@id="openDataStatic"]//table')

        num_tables = len(tables)

        for tabno in range(num_tables):

            search_path = '// *[ @ id = "openDataStatic"] / table[%d] /  tr'%tabno

            rows = response.xpath(search_path)


            for row in rows:
                local_authority = row.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract()
                last_update = row.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract()
                num_businesses = row.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract()
                xml_file_descr = row.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract()
                xml_file = row.xpath('td[4]/a/@href').extract()

                yield {'local_authority': local_authority[1],
                      'last_update':last_update[1],
                      'num_businesses':num_businesses[1],
                      'xml_file':xml_file[0],
                      'xml_file_descr':xml_file_descr[1]
                        }
```

'''

And I'm running it with

```
scrapy runspider fsa_xpath.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate though the table selectors returned by your first xpath:

```
tables = response.xpath('//*[@id="openDataStatic"]//table')
for table in tables:
    for row in table.xpath('./tr'):
        local_authority = row.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract()
```

You did this with the rows.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I thought it would have to be something subtle I was missing.I did try that before but I missed the . before the /tr.  For some reason it returned all of the rows for all of the tables, but with the . it seems to work correctly.